# npm start doesn't work after i do npm unlink

Tags: node.js, ember.js, npm, unlink

```
npm ERR! Darwin 15.6.0
npm ERR! argv "/Users/myName/.nvm/versions/node/v5.12.0/bin/node" "/Users/myName/.nvm/versions/node/v5.12.0/bin/npm" "start"
npm ERR! node v5.12.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.8.6
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! appName@1.5.1 start: `ember server`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the appName start script 'ember server'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the appName package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     ember server
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs appName
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls appName
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/myName/Documents/Dev/ember-project-name/npm-debug
```

I linked `gooey`, one of my projects, to another project: `ember`, now i wanted to unlink them
so i did `npm unlink`
then `npm start` didn't work no matter what i did.
things I've tried: 
`npm install` several times,
`bower install` several times,
`rm -rf node_modules`
`rm -rf bower_components`
`npm install` several times
`npm start` kept giving errors, like `can't find some file in gooey` or `tell author that ember server failed`

Answer (score 1):

## The solution:

### option 1:

first do `npm link` so that it installs everything it needs
then `npm install`, then `npm start` will start working again.

### option2:

if you want to unlink, do:
`npm unlink`
`npm update`
`npm start`
that should work too.
try `npm install` again before `npm start` if you have problems.